# Square matrix with all negative elements is negative definite?

Tags: calculus, matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-rank

Consider a square matrix $A$ with each element $a_{ij}<0$ $\forall i, \forall j$.

Is it true that $A$ is negative definite? Do we need $A$ symmetric to establish that?

Comment: No. Take $a_{ij} = -1$ for all $i,j$ and $v = -e_1+e_2$. Then $v\neq 0$ but $v^\top Av=0$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following $2\times 2$ matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    -3       & -4 \\
    -4       & -2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

This matrix is indefinite, but with all elements negative.
By definition, in order to define definiteness of a matrix, that matrix has to be symmetric.

Comment: I assume you're not referring to Hermitian matrix. As for real matrix, in order to define definiteness of a matrix, that matrix has to be symmetric.

Comment: Can it be positive definite?

Comment: For a matrix with all negative elements, no, it cannot. One way to see is the first order principal minor $|a_{1,1}|$ is negative.